# 2 pages on 1 with pgfpages

Tags: pgfpages

I'm sorry I know this question has been asked several times.

I would like to get a 2 pages on 1 using pgfpages as shown by the following:

```
\documentclass[french, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink = 5mm]
```

But I only get that :

[image: 2 pages, one above the other]

instead of getting the two pages side by side.

What's wrong ?

```
\documentclass[french, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{{\textsc{Figure}}}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{{\textsc{Tableau}}}}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink = 5mm, landscape]

%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{fancybox}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tabvar}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,%
% bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,%
% breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=true]%
%{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `landscape` to the `\pgfpagesuselayout` command

```
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink = 5mm,landscape]
```

And remove the `[landscape]` option from your `\usepackage{geometry}`.

Here's a minimal document that shows the correct output:

```
\documentclass[french, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink = 5mm,landscape]
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Sorry Alan and  thank you but I obtain the two pages side by side on an a4  portrait

Comment: @imotep81 But then you need to add a compilable minimal document like the one I've added to my answer that shows exactly what you're doing.

Comment: In fact it's totally correct when I compile with the Texlive of my debian distribution. When I compile with TeXwriter on Android the result is not the one I hoped. Thanks

Comment: Wrong....With your minimal document I get the same also with TeXwriter but with my initial document it doesn't work...Because I use this : \usepackage  [unicode=true,pdfusetitle, bookmarks =true, bookmarksnumbered =false, bookmarksopen =false, breaklinks =false, pdfborder= {0 0 0},backref =false, colorlinks =true ] {hyperref } and when I remove it I get what I want

Comment: @imotep81 Again, without you providing a minimal document that shows the problem, it's hard to diagnose. Adding `hyperref` to my example document doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: And more...it works if I remove hyperref package. ..

Comment: `\documentclass[french, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink = 5mm, landscape]
\usepackage{ hyperref}
\begin{document}
\lipsum


\end{document}`

Comment: @imotep81 Don't add it in comments, edit your question. (But this compiles onto a landscape page for me too.)

Comment: Well...it works if the hyperref is placed before the call of the pgfpages package